# why does reverse() prepend a server path?

Tags: django, django-views

I have several instances of my project running on my server, like so:

```
http://0.0.0.0/one

http://0.0.0.0/two
```

I also have an activation view that is accessible via:

```
http://0.0.0.0/one/activate/u/1/c/123
```

When I do reverse() on this view from django shell, the url given to me as:

```
/activate/u/1/c/123
```

So it does not include the `/one` server path. However, when I use reverse() to look up the path of the page to send in an email somewhere else in the project, reverse() seems to return the full server path + the view path, like so:

```
/one/activate/u/1/c/123
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have django.root set up in your web server?

Comment: The django.root setting is only relevant to mod_python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reverse()` is supposed to include this server path, so that you can just use it in a link and it'll work without having to change anything else in your code. But `manage.py shell` doesn't set the appropriate path prefix; that code happens in the wsgi/etc handler. This is [Django bug #16734](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16734) (which I incidentally reported :p).

You can work around this by calling `django.core.management.base.set_script_prefix` manually, presumably in your `settings.py`. For example:

```
# when running through wsgi, this will get overriden
# but it's needed for manage.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import set_script_prefix
set_script_prefix('/one/')
```

Comment: Specifically, for a WSGI compliant server, the value of 'SCRIPT_NAME' in the per request environment supplied by the server is prepended. That doesn't exist in Django shell.

Comment: Very cool - didn't know about this. BTW, you rock Graham! Your expertise is much appreciated!

Comment: Now how was I supposed to figure this out by myself without some help from an awesome person? :) Thank you, Dougal!